# Discord.js. Reaction Roles

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to script a bot that gives people a role when they click on an emoji.

My problem is that people don't get the role when they click on the emoji. When I enter the first Command `t!role` the Message with the emoji is sent correctly. However, the people reacting will not receive the role. I tried everything that was suggested in the Comments. Unfortunatley nothing seems to work.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client( { 
    intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
],
partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]
});


    else if(parts[0].toLowerCase() == "t!role") {
        let sendMessage = await message.channel.send('React with to get the role')
        sendMessage.react('')


bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user, channel) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === '8786607442820137464') {
        if(reaction.emoji.id === '8789972642138767364') {
            reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('8779841244749004804')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Bots can only give roles below their own, even if they have Administrator permissions. Make sure the role is *below* the bot's role. Use `.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));` to log any errors if giving out the roles has failed for some reason.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working and it's giving me no errors

Answer (score 0):

Discord had added a few new features in their developer portal a few months ago and most of the documentation and tutorials skip over that but it is necessary for them to be active in order to have a functional reaction roles feature.

The process to turn these on is to go to the application page of your bot, go to the bot page under the application and activate `Presence Intent` and `Server Members Intent`. Hopefully after this your reaction roles should start working.

Comment: I had that enabled but it still didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Enable partials in your client initialization. Discord.js requires you now to add partials and intent flags you actually gonna use. The `messageReactionAdd` event requires some partials as well: `REACTION`, `MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL`.

For example, this is how you should use `partials`.

```js
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    ],
    partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]
});
```

I have used the same exact code in your post, only changed a few id's on my side, and it's working as intended. As my comment before:

> Bots can only give roles below their own, even if they have Administrator permissions. Make sure the role is below the bot's role. Use `.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));` to log any errors if giving out the roles has failed for some reason.

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user, channel) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === '8786607442820137464') {
        if(reaction.emoji.id === '8789972642138767364') {
            reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('8779841244749004804')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that but now i'm getting an Error Message saying: 

ReferenceError: Intents is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\.User\Discord.Bot\index.js)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: That means you never initialized `Intents`. Somewhere in your on top in code `const { Intents } = require("discord.js")` @IneedHelp

Comment: I tried that aswell but it's just not working. The Bot is just starting as usual. The Message with the Emoji is getting sended but i don't get the role. 

I also have the Role below the Bot Role but it's just not working and idk why and no Error Messages.

Comment: @IneedHelp Does your bot have `Manage Roles` permission?

Comment: When i added the Bot i gave it the Administrator permission. But i gave him an extra Role with the Manage Roles permission.

Comment: I invited the Bot again but now with the specific permission and not only the administrator Role but it's still not working tho

Comment: @IneedHelp Could you update your question with the updated code and hierarchy (screenshot) for your roles? Also check if you have the right role ID to give your members. You could also head over to Discord.js official Discord server: https://discord.com/invite/djs